# How to convert entire table from text to int

Tags: python, text, int

I have a txt file that I read with:

```
fdata =[]
with open(fn,'rb') as fo:
     for i in xrange(1):
           fo.next()
     for line in fo:                       
           data = line.split(',')
           data = data[:23]
           fdata.append(data)    
     print fdata
```

I would like convert the entire table to numbers from string. AND limit the table size to read to XXX lines.

Comment: It looks like you are maybe reading a csv file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To limit lines, try iterating using a counter and `readlines()`:

```
maxlines = 100
lines = f.readlines()

if maxlines > len(lines):  maxlines = len(lines)

for i in xrange(maxlines):
  line = lines[i]

  # Do your stuff...
```

To convert a string to a number (an integer in this case. `float()` is for floating points):

```
print '9000' == 9000 # False.
print int('9000') == 9000 # True
```

So to make your table only include integers, convert each line (after splitting) into an integer. `int()` only *returns* an integer, so it doesn't modify your variable. Replacing `fdata.append(data))` with `fdata.append(int(data()` should do the trick.

---

Okay, to convert your entire list into integers, just iterate over each of those 23 elements to convert them into integers. This works for an arbitrary list of strings:

```
for element in data:
  element = int(element)
```

---

To convert your list into integers, but to exclude your first element, loop through it:

```
for i in xrange(1, len(data)): # I used 1 because 0 is the first element. This skips it.
  data[i] = int(data[i])
```

Comment: Replace `fdata.append(data)` with `fdata.append(int(data))` to make your table consist of integers.

Comment: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

Comment: Just an FYI, in Python, they are called 'lists', not 'tables'. It's the name of the datatype, and it's a bit less ambiguous.

Comment: I thought I had 23 element, first is date, then 22 elements

Comment: What about using for element in data: element = int(element) then element [0] as str(element)

Comment: If element 0 is not a number, it will cause an exception. If you just need it to be of type `int`, then your solution works perfectly.

Comment: Any luck? If you found an answer, accept it. It helps others with the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertool import islice
fdata =[]
with open(fn,'rb') as fo:
     for i in xrange(1):
           fo.next()
     for line in islice(fo,0,XXX):                       
           data = line.split(',')
           data = data[:23]
           fdata.append(map(int,data))    
     print fdata
```

Comment: I think the OP won't understand what `islice()` and `map()` functions do *just* yet. But +1 for showing me what `map()` does!

Comment: @Blender, well the documentation is very good and not difficult to find :)

Comment: @Blender: it's the same as `fdata.append(int(x) for x in data)`

Comment: I'm trying to be nice and keeping it simple. I don't think the OP has learned list comprehensions yet...

Comment: @Blender, it's actually a generator expression, list comprehensions use `[]`. perhaps `islice` is a little harder to learn, but `readlines()` can be evil because it reads the entire file into memory at once.